# System.FormatException has been thrown input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, streamreader

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FajlbolOlvasas
{
    class Program
    {
        struct Student
        {
            public string name;
            public double avarage;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader f = new StreamReader("joci.txt");
            Student[] students = new Student[Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine())];
            for (int i = 0; i < tanulok.Length && !f.EndOfStream; i++)
            {
                students[i].name = f.ReadLine();
                students[i].avarage = Convert.ToDouble(f.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(students[i].name + " - " + students[i].avarage);
            }
            f.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The txt file was saved at bin/Release 
the console appears but that is just an empty one 
it says System.FormatException has been thrown input string was not in a correct format

the content of the txt file is :
Tomi
4
Lee
3
Bob
5

Comment: Which line raises the error? Also formatting your code will help people understand it.

Comment: Ideally, convert this to a [mcve]. It's really hard to help you find a problem with the input data when we can't see the input data.

Comment: Change Student[] students = new Student[Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine())];                                    To Student[] students = new Student[Convert.ToDobule(f.ReadLine())];

Comment: im super newbie i forget to commit

Comment: You should also include the content of your input file.

Comment: I suppose that any of your lines isn´t parsable to double, probably because you use a comma as decimal-character and use culture `en-US`. Buth without any idea on your file this is hard to guess.

Comment: @W.Groom I changed if i change it it says that 'System.convert' does not contain a definition for 'toDouble' do i have to use a package for this ?

Comment: Please post the txt file you are using we can't help you like this

Comment: @fadiBanna I posted to content of the txt file

Comment: @JózsefPallagi and you still do not see the probelm? `StreamReader f = new StreamReader("joci.txt"); Student[] students = new Student[Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine())];`

Comment: @m.rogalski no i dont :/ an empty console displays and it says ASystem.FormatException was thrown. input string was not in a corret  format.

Comment: @PJoe your file contents starts with line "Tomi" and first line you are trying to convert to `int`.

Comment: You need to stop coding and learn how to debug.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: it took me 1 hour to figure out :/  :(
i changed int32.parse(f.ReadLine()); 
@m.rogalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so besides of the main problem which is FormatException i see few others.

First one is that you are processing "unknown" file contents into an array instead of list. This can be skipped if you know how the file is structured using example below:

```
string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines("joci.txt");
Student[] students = new Student[fileContents.Lengthe / 2]; // because 2 lines describes student
```

But better solution is to do this using `List<>` instead of array :

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
```

Next thing that is **totally** wrong is that you're assuming that you know the file contents. You should always leave some margin for errors, and first try to convert type instead of demanding type conversion:

```
string line = f.ReadLine();
int convertedLine = 0;
if ( int.TryParse( line, out convertedLine ) ) {
    // now convertedLine is succesfully converted into integer type.
}
```

So making the final conclusion :

**ALWAYS** leave some margin for errors.

The **good** ( but still not the best ) solution for your problem would be :

```
string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines("joci.txt");
Student[] students = new Student[fileContents.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fileContents.Length; i += 2, j++)
{
    string name = fileContents[i];
    int av = 0;
    if ( int.TryParse( fileContents[i + 1], out av ) {
        students[j] = new Student { name = name, average = av };
        Console.WriteLine(students[j].name + " - " + students[j].avarage);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```